# Animating a suiting up effect

Tags: modifiers, physics, cloth-simulation, effects

I am attempting to create an animation of a character suiting up in a full body suit and I’m wondering what might be a good way to achieve this? I currently have two models - the character and the character suited up. For visual reference the type of thing I’m going for is something like this comic: [image]

I’ve looked at maybe using the cloth modifier but getting it to animate from cloth hanging to a standard mesh is something I’m not sure about. An alternative method I thought about was rigging the suit with a ton of bones and basically manually animate them, but that seems like it would require hundreds of bones and would behave like a suit physically would. Are there any other methods or ways of doing this that would be viable?
Thanks for any help!